# check strength of password

Tags: python, passwords

I'm not looking for someone to give me the solution.
I'm just seeking a little help to why this doesn't work.
This is also a little bit different than the other password strength questions available

```
def password(pwd):
        if len(pwd) >= 10:
            is_num = False
            is_low = False
            is_up = False
            for ch in pwd:
                if ch.isdigit():
                    is_num = True
                if ch.islower():
                    is_low = True
                if ch.isupper():
                    is_up = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert password(u'A1213pokl') == False, "1st example"
    assert password(u'bAse730onE4') == True, "2nd example"
    assert password(u'asasasasasasasaas') == False, "3rd example"
    assert password(u'QWERTYqwerty') == False, "4th example"
    assert password(u'123456123456') == False, "5th example"
    assert password(u'QwErTy911poqqqq') == True, "6th example"
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your `password` function doesn't `return` anything. It will always return `None`.

Comment: You have not stated what you are actually looking for the function to do. You check the return value but there isn't any. Please describe the desired results of the function call.

Comment: i kept putting return True under the last if statement instead of return is_num and is_low and is_up.  then i did not return False for the beginning if conditional statement.  the issue has been resolved and i'm extremely greatful for the amount of support this thread has shown me.  Thank you all

Comment: could anybody help explain why this was down voted?  i'm trying to understand the reputation a little more.  i've read about it, but the way i created this thread, i'm trying to understand why it was down voted.  i see a few people suggested they didn't see where i asked the question, but the question is in the title.  "I'm just seeking a little help to why this doesn't work" <--- this is what i was seeking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing 2 return statements to make this work:

```
def password(pwd):
    if len(pwd) >= 10:
        is_num = False
        is_low = False
        is_up = False
        for ch in pwd:
            if ch.isdigit():
                is_num = True
            if ch.islower():
                is_low = True
            if ch.isupper():
                is_up = True
        return is_num and is_low and is_up
    return False
```

Comment: oh wow!  thanks man!  this was bobbling the heck out of my mind!

Comment: Hi @ryeth if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this though.

Comment: not a problem.  i'll do that now.  i'm very sorry as this is the first time i've really used stackoverflow and i will be using it much more often now.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
    def password(pwd):
        upper = any(ch.isupper() for ch in pwd)
        lower = any(ch.islower() for ch in pwd)
        is_dig = any(ch.isdigit() for ch in pwd)
        return  upper and lower and is_dig and len(pwd) > 10
```

Comment: Trilinear time solution? :(

Comment: looping 3 times trough the string. slower than doing all checks in one loop, even if more readable.
trilinear means three times linear.
linear, by itself means the time it takes to complete is proportional to the number of elements in the list.
still, nice solution, much more pythonic :)